# CSS: Remove whitespace at top(already made reset margin/padding)

Tags: css, html

I'm having a little trouble figuring out why I have about 10px of whitespace at the top of my html file. In CSS, I made the margin and padding 0 in "body" but it still is there. Any help? Thanks!

Update: So I found out that removing the !doctype html at the top removes the white space with google chrome browser but not with firefox. But from my research, you need the !doctype html to tell the browser that its html5 so I don't know where to go from here.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Personal WebSite</title>


    <style>

    html body{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }


     #topbar {
     background-color:#0876BB;
     width:100%;
     height:40px;
     color:#343436;
    }

    #derek{
      float:left;
      font-size: 1.3em;
      padding-left:100px;
      padding-top:5px;
      font-weight:bold;
    }

    #Menu{
      padding-right: 30px;
    }
        #Menu li{
            float:right;
            font-size: 1.3em;
            font-weight: bold;
            display:inline;
            margin:5px 10px 0px 0px;

            cursor:pointer;
        }
            li:hover{
              color:red;
            }

    .break{
      clear:both;
    }

    #title{
      position:absolute;
    }
    img{
      position:relative;
      opacity:0.6;
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
    }


    </style>

    <body>
        <div id="topbar">

            <div id="derek">Derek</div>

            <div id="Menu">
                 <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>About</li>
                    <li>Portfolio</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="break"></div>

        <div id="title">
        <h1>Web Development</h1>
        <img src="http://www.wallpapersdb.org/wallpapers/nature/calm_water_2048x1152.jpg" target="_blank">
        </div>


    </body>


    </head>
    </html>
```

Comment: See `padding-top:5px;` , `font-size: 1.3em;` at `#derek`

Comment: I tried removing both of those and it is still there...the whitespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The margin on your ul is causing the grief.

I've updated the css to remove the margin

To trouble shoot this, I just removed elements until I found the block of html that was causing the issue.

```css
html body{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }


     #topbar {
     background-color:#0876BB;
     width:100%;
     height:40px;
     color:#343436;
    }

    #derek{
      float:left;
      font-size: 1.3em;
      padding-left:100px;
      padding-top:5px;
      font-weight:bold;
    }

    #Menu{
      padding-right: 30px;
    }
        #Menu ul {
        margin : 0;
        }
        #Menu li{
            float:right;
            font-size: 1.3em;
            font-weight: bold;
            display:inline;
            margin:5px 10px 0px 0px;

            cursor:pointer;
        }
            li:hover{
              color:red;
            }

    .break{
      clear:both;
    }

    #title{
      position:absolute;
    }
    img{
      position:relative;
      opacity:0.6;
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Personal WebSite</title>
    <body>
        <div id="topbar">
            <div id="derek">Derek</div>

            <div id="Menu">
                 <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>About</li>
                    <li>Portfolio</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="break"></div>

        <div id="title">
        <h1>Web Development</h1>
        <img src="http://www.wallpapersdb.org/wallpapers/nature/calm_water_2048x1152.jpg" target="_blank">
        </div>


    </body>


    </head>
    </html>
```

Comment: My pleasure, css can be a bind like that.

Answer (score 1):

The **ul** from your head, you need to add **margin-top: 0;** he is the cause of your top margin